# How can I sort curly- and open/closed brackets?

Tags: pascal

my teacher want me to sort a random amount of brackets.
I tried to solve this problem myself... However, I find my solution bad and hope someone has a better idea.

The string only contains these characters: ()[]{} ...
So first of all I checked the length of the string and then made the case-statement count every character to save the number in variables.
After that I used the value in the variables to get my wanted output.

```
program counter;

uses SysUtils, crt;

var
  character: String;
  k1_open,k2_open,k3_open,k1_closed,k2_closed,k3_closed : Integer;
  i : Integer;

begin
    writeln('sort brackets (1. Version)');
    write('Input: ');readln(character);

    for i := 1 to length(character) do
    begin
        case character[i] of
        '(' : k1_open    :=  k1_open + 1;
        '[' : k2_open    :=  k2_open + 1;
        '{' : k3_open    :=  k3_open + 1;
        ')' : k1_closed  :=  k1_closed + 1;
        ']' : k2_closed  :=  k2_closed + 1;
        '}' : k3_closed  :=  k3_closed + 1;
        end;
    end;

    if (k1_open = 1) and (k1_closed = 1) then begin
        write('()');
    end else if (k1_open = 2) and (k1_closed = 2) then begin
        write('()()');
    end else if (k1_open = 3) and (k1_closed = 3) then begin
        write('()()()');
    end;

    if (k2_open = 1) and (k2_closed = 1) then begin
        write('[]');
    end else if (k2_open = 2) and (k2_closed = 2) then begin
        write('[][]');
    end else if (k2_open = 3) and (k2_closed = 3) then begin
        write('[][][]');
    end;

    if (k3_open = 1) and (k3_closed = 1) then begin
        write('{}');
    end else if (k3_open = 2) and (k3_closed = 2) then begin
        write('{}{}');
    end else if (k3_open = 3) and (k3_closed = 3) then begin
        write('{}{}{}');
    end;
end.
```

Examples:

---

```
Input: [{])]}(

Output: {}[]()
```

---

```
Input: [(}{[])}(]{)

Output:{}{}[][]()()
```

---

```
Input: [][}}](

Output: Error - brackets do not match.
```

---

As I said - I have the wanted outcome... but I think it's badly implemented.
But I couldn't find a better soulution.

I hope you can help me - thanks!

Comment: First of all, set all `k`-variables to zero. Instead of testing `open`/`closed` count for 1,2,3 etc, test for equality. Then print the number of brackets using the count variable in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are global, so they will be initialized to 0, but otherwise, you may want to set *k1_open* etc. to 0.

You can improve code like this:

```delphi
    if (k1_open = 1) and (k1_closed = 1) then begin
        write('()');
    end else if (k1_open = 2) and (k1_closed = 2) then begin
        write('()()');
    end else if (k1_open = 3) and (k1_closed = 3) then begin
        write('()()()');
    end;

    if (k2_open = 1) and (k2_closed = 1) then begin
        write('[]');
    end else if (k2_open = 2) and (k2_closed = 2) then begin
        write('[][]');
    end else if (k2_open = 3) and (k2_closed = 3) then begin
        write('[][][]');
    end;

    if (k3_open = 1) and (k3_closed = 1) then begin
        write('{}');
    end else if (k3_open = 2) and (k3_closed = 2) then begin
        write('{}{}');
    end else if (k3_open = 3) and (k3_closed = 3) then begin
        write('{}{}{}');
    end;
```

into something like:

```delphi
    if (k1_open = k1_closed) and
       (k2_open = k2_closed) and
       (k3_open = k3_closed) then 
    begin
      for i := 1 to k1_open do 
        Write('()');
      for i := 1 to k2_open do 
        Write('[]');
      for i := 1 to k3_open do 
        Write('{}');
      Writeln;
    end 
    else
      Writeln('Brackets do not match')
  end.
```

The improved version can handle larger numbers than three of each kind of bracket too.